# Update state before render

Tags: javascript, react-native, render, asyncstorage

I want to fetch a condition from AsyncStorage and on the basis of that render the appropriate screen. But it seems that the method in which I update the state being in useEffect is called after rendering. Does anyone know how to update state form asyncnstorage before render is called?

Comment: You can't do that

Comment: What is the solution to it? Since I want to render my screen based on state of data.

Comment: [Conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can probably use [React-Native-MMKV](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-mmkv) storage over AsyncStorage, MMKV is 20x faster. async(245ms) vs MMKV(12ms)

since you want your TTI(time to interaction) to be lowest due to data being fetched, this is the best option.

or if you wana stick to async you can prefetch data in a prev screen and then pass it to your comp, if your UX allows